# Load one SWF with attached .as into another?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I'm trying to set up a proof-of-concept of loading one SWF into another SWF for skinning. The set-up is this:

- `app.fla`, which has an attached ActionScript class, `AppMain.as`
- `skin.fla`, which contains UI components

`AppMain.as` will obviously contain all of the application's logic; I then want to be able to affect the UI components contained within the loaded skin file based on instance names defined in that particular skin.

So for example, if I have  a `TextField` with an instance name of `myTextField` I'd like to be able to set the `text` property of that text field programmatically in `AppMain.as`.

The exported `app.swf` to load a skin file based on a `flashvar` parameter would be loaded into an HTML document that looked like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="swf"><!--//--></div>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="swfobject.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#swf').flash({
                  swf: 'app.swf',
                  width: 550,
                  height: 400,
                  flashvars: {
                      skin: 'skin.swf'
                  }
              });
          });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This simply loads `app.swf` into the `#swf` `<div>`. Any help on how to get the skin SWF into my main app SWF would be grateful. I currently have the following (which does not work).

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class AppMain extends MovieClip
    {
        public function AppMain()
        {
            var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            self.addChild(myLoader);
            var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('skin.swf');
            myLoader.load(myRequest);
        }
    }   
}
```

The skin I'm trying to load is simple in that it has a red background so I can see if it's been loaded or not; it's not as my HTML page where I'm exporting to still has a white background.

Do I have an error above? The console in Flash Professional CS5 is not giving me any errors under the "Compile Errors" tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with smaller modifications and it worked fine for me. First of all check this line:

```
    self.addChild(myLoader);
```

If your code what you wrote here is complete, the self variable is not declared (but in this case you should get an "Access of undefined property" error).
If that variable is declared, check that is added to the display list or not. Your problem can be reproduced in that case when it not added: you don't see your loaded stuff, and don't get any errors.

If it still not helps, try to add some event listeners to your Loader instance to see what happening during the load process.

```
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.INIT, initHandler );
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.OPEN, openHandler );
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.UNLOAD , unLoadHandler );
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE , completeHandler );
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR , ioErrorHandler );
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS , progressHandler );
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS , httpStatusHandler );
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR , securityErrorHandler);
```

If you have any other questions, please ask.

Cheers

Tamas Gronas

Comment: Thanks, Tamas. I'll give these suggestions a go and report back here with my findings.

Comment: Interesting. The skin SWF *was* being loaded. I set the background colour of the skin SWF to red, but it was transparent when being loaded as I added some text (in yellow) and the yellow text has appeared (albeit on a white background).

Comment: How can I pick up a flashvar in my `AppMain` constructor method? I've tried `this.loaderInfo.parameters.skin` to pick out a flashvar called "skin" but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Ignore me. Got it working. It was an error in my JavaScript (I was passing the skin value as a `params` object member rather than as the required `flashvars` object). School boy error!